# It seems that my JSX code generation cells(HTML td element) has some problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently encountered a problem when doing the react table experiment, that is, I used an array map method to extract the prepared data and generate td html element. But I can't generate it after the data is successfully taken out. What is going on?

as shown in the following code:

```
{this.state.isSearch && Object.entries(this.state.fake).map(innerArray => {
                        console.log(this.state.searchTarget);
                        if (
                          innerArray[1][0]
                            .toUpperCase()
                            .indexOf(this.state.searchTarget.toUpperCase()) != -1
                        ) {
                          console.log("got it!");
                          <tr>
                            {innerArray[1].map(value => {
                              <td>{value}</td>;
                              console.log(value);
                            })}
                          </tr>;
                        }
})}
```

The data needed to run is here:

```
state = {
    fake: {
      ALARM: ["a", 2, 3, 4, 5],
      WARNING: ["b", 11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
      PISTON: ["c", 222, 333, 444, 555],
      ROLLER: ["d", 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555],
      POWDER: ["e", 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555],
      CHAMBER: ["f", 222222, 333333, 444444, 555555]
    },
    isSearch: true,
    searchTarget: "a"
}
```

the Google dev tools run result:

```
a
got it!
a
2
3
4
5
...
```

The data was successfully read, but the expression that generated the HTML td element was not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything. Try to add return statements

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I’m sorry, I didn’t make it clear. It’s just a small part of my code. In fact, it already has a render() method and a return.

Comment: Wait, it seems like this... I forgot to return the value after the JavaScript code has finished running..... ⊙ o ⊙